# I can not find any information on how to properly use the "Period" predicate under the WHERE clause

Tags: sql, predicate

So I'm encountering a frustrating issue where I have NO reasonable idea what the "period" predicate means and how to use it under my WHERE clause. This query was passed down to me for my job and so I am now trying to break it down. The numbers in the investment_account_id and loan_id list are fake as the real ones are confidential and not very important to the overall query issue I have.

Is the period predicate being used correctly and if so, can you please break down what it means? Is it for results only on that one day, up to that day, as of that day or how does it work? I have tried googling and can't seem to find reference to this predicate ANYWHERE

For context, this query's results are supposed to be rows where the loan_id and investment_account_id match for a monthly report. This is used to denote which complaints are tied to certain investors for that month

```
select  
    loan_id,
    investment_account_id
from    
    TABLE
where
    **period = '2021-05-31'**
    and investment_account_id in ('12345',
    '54321',
    '52314',
    '12233',
    '65321')
    and loan_id in ('112233',
    '332211',
    '542131')
```

Comment: i think you must have a start time and end time of the period, so you should have that informatio in your table or in your home work

Comment: What RDBMS is this? Is `period` just a column on the table?

Comment: There's most likely a column called `period` in your table...

Comment: Oh my gosh I am so sorry everyone I'm a bit new to SQL and I believe it is just a column called period! I was too caught up in the semantics of it all and didn't even stop to think that it could've been a column!